# Retrieve array of data from SQLite, retrieve attributes from array, and add attributes into an array and create a polyline

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

I am able to retrieve a List from my database with `routeID`, `routeName`, `lat` and `lng` like so:

```
    DatabaseRouteHelper db = new DatabaseRouteHelper(this);
    List<Route> routesWithSameID;
    Intent routeID = getIntent();
    int routeid = routeID.getIntExtra("routeID", 0);

    routesWithSameID = db.getAllRoutesWithSameID(routeid);
```

I am wondering how can I extract all the lat and lngs (`getLat()` and `getLng()`)
and add them into another array list so it only has the lat and lngs for me to be able to create a polyline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've got it, just needed to iterate through the array, get the values, parse em and add to a LatLng array like so:

```
List<LatLng> latLng = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

for (int i = 0; i < routesWithSameID.size(); i++){
            String latString = routesWithSameID.get(i).getLat();
            String lngString = routesWithSameID.get(i).getLng();
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latString);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(lngString);
            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            latLng.add(location);
        }
```